# drywall patch replacement

Tags: repair, drywall, patch

I used a patch kit to fix a 1/4" hole in drywall and the patch is too raised and visible. Is there a way I can undo the patch and try a different solution? There are 2 separate holes, both are patched and sanded, one also has primer over it.

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: You are supposed to build the mud up on top of the patch and then taper it down to the existing wall surface. It takes skill.

Answer (score -1):

I recently learned on a trrick on ajob site for this problem. Use a utility knife to cut around the hole. Use some thing as a template to trace aroud before cuttng. 
Then use the same template and cut anew pice of sheet rock the same size. But taper it like you would if you were cutting the top of a jack o lantern. It will slide in perfectly with a little mud around the edges it will stay in place and stay flush or just slightly off. 
You can then fill or sand to get it flush.

It works perfect and is very easy. Not a lot of skill involved

Comment: No tape? Sounds like a recipe for cracking failure to me.